# With Calabash for Android, how can write a step that scrolls to and touchs a specific listview row?

Tags: android, cucumber, calabash

I want to write a Cucumber step definition that scrolls to and selects a specific row in an Android ListView. On iOS I can do the following:

```
scroll_to_cell(:row => 1, :section => 0)
touch("tableViewCell indexPath:1,0")
```

How would I do the same thing on Android?

**Update**: In the calabash-android source, I've found a function called each_item which iterates over every item in a list view. However, I can't quite figure out how it would be valuable yet since it only returns an integer for it's position in the listview as opposed to the item itself. So, I can't do something like...

```
each_item do |product|
    touch(product)
end
```

The function lives here: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/operations.rb#L145

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a general solution. Android solution will depend on ListView implementation.

---

The solution that will work for particular ListView is below:

1) First of all, perform `query("ListView", {:getItemAtPosition => 1})` and look the property in query result that equals to the text in GUI. For instance, it can be `"name"`.

2) Then you can touch item in specific position with the following step:

```
Then /^I click the (\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th) list item$/ do |row|
  scroll_to_row("ListView", row+1)
  touch "* text:\"#{query("ListView", {:getItemAtPosition => row+1})[0]["name"]}\""  
end
```

I've verified it in my Android app, it works.